# Disable confirm navigation if page is postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have included a script that prompts "confirm navigation" when user makes changes on the form
here is the code:

```
var warning = true;
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (warning) {
            return "You have made changes on this page that you have not yet confirmed.   If you navigate away from this page you will lose your unsaved changes";
        }
    }

    $('claimformmain').submit(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
```

my problem is I have a function that has postback, can I disable the script if page is postback? thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to happen? If the page has posted back and reloaded, you don't want the confirm message to appear? That doesn't make sense to me. Your question is confusingly worded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Add one hidden field in Your HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnIsPostBack" value="false" />
```

Write in your code behind

```
if(Page.IsPostBack)
    hdnIsPostBack.Value = "true";
else
    hdnIsPostBack.Value = "false";
```

And your Jquery function is go this way.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if( $('#hdnIsPostBack').val() == "true")
    {
        //Your Function goes here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a click event to your postback control where you can set window.onbeforeunload to null.